# WD calendar, getting value out of drop down

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am adding WD calendar to project I'm working (http://www.webappers.com/2010/06/08/wdcalendar-jquery-based-google-calendar-clone/). Basicly I have to remake all "Add New Event" form. The thing is, I cant seem to get dropdown values out of time input.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        //debugger;
        var DATA_FEED_URL = "php/datafeed.php";
        var arrT = [];
        var tt = "{0}:{1}";
        for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            arrT.push({ text: StrFormat(tt, [i >= 10 ? i : "0" + i, "00"]) }, { text: StrFormat(tt, [i >= 10 ? i : "0" + i, "30"]) });
        }
        $("#timezone").val(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60 * -1);
        $("#stparttime").dropdown({

            dropheight: 200,
            dropwidth:60,
            selectedchange: function() {
              var startH= $("li .hover div").html();
             console.log(startH);
               },
            items: arrT
        });
```

Input

```
<input MaxLength="5" class="required time" id="stparttime" name="stparttime" style="width:50px; margin-right:5px;" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($event)?$sarr[1]:""; ?>" />To                       
          <input MaxLength="50" class="required time" id="etparttime" name="etparttime" style="width:50px;" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($event)?$earr[1]:""; ?>" />
```

Also, i cant modify too much time input (which sadly is not select), beacaus it will affect badly callendar functions.

Picture of my form
http://oi59.tinypic.com/2e5ioau.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. input #stparttime, saves selected li's html as value. Probably I had some typo when I tried it at first.